# complex recursion formula for finding partitions

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to calculate partitions of a natural number using the formula below. The formula generates two positive numbers, then two negative and so on. You stop when P(n) < 0 An example is

```
  p(3) = p(2) + p(1) = 3
  p(4) = p(3) + p(2) = 3 + 2 = 5
  p(5) = p(4) + p(3) -  p(0) = 5 + 3 - 1 = 7
  p(6) = p(5)  + p(4) - p(1) = 7 + 5 - 1 = 11
  *P(0) = 1 by convention
```

In other words in order to calculate say P(5) you would have to calculate P(4) which equals P(3) + P(2) and and P(3) which equals P(2) + P(1) and finally - P(0) which equals 1. You would have to traverse down for each to find what they equal and then sum them. So to find a partition of a number you would have to find the partitions of all other numbers each. I have tried something as you can see the code below but it does not work. k = counter in my code.

[image]

```
    Code:
    public static long SerialFib( long n ) 
    { 
        long exponent = 0;
        double ex;
        long counter = 1;
        ex = Math.pow(-1, counter - 1);
        exponent = (long) ex;
        if (n < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {

            return SerialFib((exponent * (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) - 1)) / 
            2)))) + SerialFib((exponent * (n - ( (counter * ( (3 * counter) +1))/2))));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter is going to always be 1 because you aren't passing it back into SerialFib. Also, you need a base case for when n is equal to 0 it will return 1.

first base case:

```
if(n==0)
   return 1;
```

SerialFib should have another parameter for counter:

```
SerialFib(long n, int counter)
```

When you call SerialFib it should look like:

```
SerialFib( [your formula], ++counter);
```